# gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

```
  def make_req(data, url, method='POST')  
    params = urllib.urlencode(data)
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               "Accept": "text/plain",
               }
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url)
    conn.request(method, url, params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    response_data = response.read()
    conn.close()
```

But it is throwing: `in create_connection for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM): gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

What is the reason ? What is this error?

Answer (score 7):

You need to call request() with the URI relative to the server. If `url`  is `www.google.com/images?q=test` you have to do:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com')
conn.request('GET', '/images?q=test')
```