# How to upgrade pip in virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

This question has already been asked here, though there is no answer solving this problem.

[pip upgrade fails inside virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023680/pip-upgrade-fails-inside-virtual-environment)

The **above question is duplicate** and the references following answer:

[gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221848/gaierror-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known)

But this answer doesnot contain anything valid. The former answer also does not contain any helpful info!

My problem is exactly what is described in first link. **I try upgrade pip from 10.0.1 to 18.1 but unable to**. As a consequence I am unable to install Tensorflow. This Virtual environment is actually connected to pycharm and I am referencing it through command line. Here is the input and corresponding commandline output:

```
(venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>pip install --upgrade pip
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


(venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in g:\ashish\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)

(venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from g:\ashish\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg\pip (python 3.7)

(venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>pip install --upgrade pip
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


(venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>
```

I tried uninstalling the pip from virtual environment. I did not work. I am sorry if this is basic or involves basic knowledge about virtual env, This is my learning phase and some time before I can start to contribute to this awesome community.

Comment: In the last line of your log it's clearly stating `You should consider upgrading via the python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.` So try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command` and see if it works.

Comment: (venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in g:\ashish\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)

Comment: I would not have wasted time if it was this simple Rahul

Comment: Now try doing `python -m pip --version` and tell the result.

Comment: (venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>python -m pip --version
pip 18.1 from G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)


                     
(venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from g:\ashish\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: so your command says it's 18.1 and then pip --version says it's 10.0.1

Comment: So the `pip` in your virtual environment is `18.1` while the global `pip` is `10.0.1`. So your issue is solved.

Comment: When you do `python -m pip` from a virtual environment, it chooses the virtual environment's `pip`. When you do just `pip` it chooses the global `pip`. So when you do `python -m pip --version` it chose the `venv`'s pip and gave that version, but when you do just `pip --version` it gets global pip version.

Comment: Ahh, it makes perfect sense! Let me fix it and see if that works.

Comment: If you want to upgrade global pip, first exit the `venv` by typing `deactivate` and then run `python -m pip instal --upgrade pip`. This will choose global `pip` since you're not in a `venv`.

Comment: But the error still stays the same while installing tensorflow

Comment: Collecting tensorflow

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: What is that error, could you paste that please?

Comment: pip install tensorflow <<  I took this from pypi after following tensorflow's documentation. This states I need atleast pip 12. I have 18.1 now, still it gives this : Collecting tensorflow Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: The same error occurs in Pycharm too, which makes it slightly more annoying.

Comment: ok, so staying in your virtual environment do : `python -m pip install tensorflow`.

Comment: To illustrate that I tried hard, I tried installing anaconda. I installed everything, but while doing conda install tensorflow, I can leave it for hours and it still shows : Solving environment /

Comment: (venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>python -m pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: `ternsorflow` is not available for Python 3.7; install Python 3.6 if you need it.

Comment: Ok, try this answer: `python -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: (venv) G:\Ashish\Tensorflow\venv\Scripts>python -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh
Collecting https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh
  HTTP error 404 while getting https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh

Comment: Could not install requirement https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh because of error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh
Could not install requirement https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.wh for URL https:....

Comment: This gives this error. I did try this as well:( This is sad, Thank you for trying. I am trying what "@hoefling" suggested. Can you please remove the downvote? With python 3.6, let me try this command. I am almost certain it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved the problem, thanks to suggestions of @hoefling and@Rahul Bhardwaj

For python environment showing 10.0.1 and 18.1:

```
pip in your virtual environment is 18.1 while the global pip is 10.0.1. So the issue is solved, simply upgrade global pip
```

For tensorflow not installing:

```
Install python 3.6
Add that to path 
Create a virtual environment in pycharm using python 3.6 
Install tensorflow
```

Done! Python 3.7 is yet to support tensorflow